# Replacing image on the post with If

Tags: html, css, image

Hello there everybody.

I need your help here on replacing an image.

Actually i'm working on blogger with CSS and HTML. I want in some posts the background image to be replaced by another.

The Original css has this :

```
body{
    background:#000000 url(image.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    color:#fff;
    font:x-small Georgia Serif;
    font-size:small;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

So on some posts i use this css "trick to replace the original background image with another (inside the post)

```
body{
    background:#000000 url(image2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    color:#fff;
    font:x-small Georgia Serif;
    font-size:small;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Can i add something like

If div class="post1" 
don't download the image1. Download only the image2.

So that in the post the browser doesn't need to download both images and takes time further.

Thanks and sorry in advance if the question is noobish.

Comment: Have you tried setting the default `background` as image1.jpg and write a block for `.post1 { background-image: url(image2.jpg); }` http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/97bs6kkr/

Answer (score 0):

Give the body a class, and define the background in the class.

Page one:

```
<body class="background1">*Content*</body>
```

Page two:

```
<body class="background2">*Content*</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  color:#fff;
  font:small Georgia Serif;
  text-align:left;
  margin:0;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}

.background1 { background:#000000 url(image1.jpg) no-repeat top center; }
.background2 { background:#000000 url(image2.jpg) no-repeat top center; }
```

Comment: Actually with this we dont have any default image to be replaced. I want an image for the 99% of the pages of the blog+homepage. And an image witch replaced the first for some posts only. Thanks for your answer and time though :)

Comment: No, but he says that he don't want to load image1, if it is image2 that should be shown.

Comment: i think i may need a <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'> in order to use this css if default pages or use this css if the other pages.but i dont have the knowledg to make this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the default `body { background ...` as image1.jpg and write a block for

```
.post1 { 
  background-image: url(image2.jpg);
}
```

And utilize the `class` of the `body` element on a case by case basis as you need to override the default `body` `background-image`?

http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/97bs6kkr/